# Self invoked function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain why the code executes , but when I inspect the error persists saying

> "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function "

when I do

```
(alert("hi"))();
```

Comment: Well... It first executes the alerts and then tries to executes what the alert returns, which is undefined...

Comment: That's not really a self invoked function, just some parenthesis ?

Comment: just write `alert('Hi');`

Comment: How do you come with such code. This looks so random...

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to know what actually (//some code here, may be functions or expressions) () , does here

Comment: I was just confused with the difference between                          var b = function abc(){alert('hi')}; AND                         (function abc(){alert('hi')});

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
(alert("hi"))();
```

is NOT a self invoked function. This would be a self invoked function:

```
(function(){alert("hi");})();
```

Notice how it's a `function`.

The first case, you are trying to invoke what is returned by `alert`. Unfortunately, alert returns `undefined`, so what you are effectively doing is:

```
alert("hi");
undefined();
```

And as the error says, `undefined is not a function`

The later is almost (but not exactly) equivalent to doing something like this:

```
function foo() {
   alert("hi");
}
foo();
```

But allows you to invoke the *anonymous* function immediately without having to give it a name.

Note: If, instead of `alert` you called a function that returns a function, then your original syntax would be perfectly valid (if a little hard to read). For example, you could do this:

```
function myalert(str) { 
    return function() { alert(str); }
};

(myalert("hi"))();
```

But your extra brackets would be completely unnecessary because you could just as easily do:

```
myalert("hi")();
```

Comment: +1 ["iffy"'s](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) for the win...

Comment: Thanks a lot , I got it now :)

Answer (score 1):

`alert("hi")` returns `undefined` which you are then invoking, causing the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the alert function correctly:

```
alert("I am an alert box!");
```

It is not a self invoked function at all. Read about the alert function [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)